# I have a problem in running angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a material.module.ts file and set all of config files, but I can not run the  application.

I want to use material component in my application, but I get errors and warnings. Please help me resolve them.

```
platform.es5.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at platform.es5.js:102
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js (platform.es5.js:104)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js (a11y.es5.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/autocomplete.es5.js (autocomplete.es5.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/material.es5.js (material.es5.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/material/material.module.ts (gridcomponent.component.ts:29)
```

I get this warning

```
[WDS] Warnings while compiling.
warnings @ client:148
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/overlay.es5.js 5043:68-86
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/datepicker.es5.js 101:59-77
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/text-field.es5.js 146:57-75
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 314:60-78
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/layout.es5.js 88:54-72
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 195:57-75
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/observers.es5.js 38:65-83
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/core.es5.js 1452:59-77
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
warnings @ client:154
onmessage @ socket.js:41
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ sockjs.js:170
(anonymous) @ sockjs.js:887
SockJS._transportMessage @ sockjs.js:885
EventEmitter.emit @ sockjs.js:86
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ sockjs.js:2961
wrapFn @ zone.js:1332
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
client:154 ./node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js 1027:57-75
"export 'ɵɵdefineInjectable' was not found in '@angular/core'
```

I use material version  8.0.1 and cdk version is 8.0.1 and angular animation version is 7.2.15 in my dependency file.

Please help me find out how to correct these errors and warning.

Comment: what is your "@angular/compiler-cli" version?

Comment: You can't use @angular/material and @angular/cdk version 8.0.1 since your angular dependencies is still at 7.2.0 try to install material 7.2.0.

Comment: post your 'package.json' file here

Answer (score 0):

> Please update your other core angular depencies to version 8, hope that solves your problem.
>
> Sample package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.13.9",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.0.0",
    "@engage3/common-lib": "0.0.43",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.0.1",
}
```